# Beautifulsoup removes end tag which in turn breaks jinja templates

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, tags, jinja2, html-parsing

I am modifying a xhtml file using BeautifulSoup4.

The problem I have right now is that it changes this:

```
<Viewpoint ... ></Viewpoint>
```

to this:

```
<Viewpoint ... />
```

which in turn does not work with jinja templates, as it failed to load the template file (xhtml) correctly.

Is there some option in BeautifulSoup4 to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not fix the root problem, but I used a workaround. Adding one space character inside the tags prohibits BeautifulSoup from removing the end tag. The space character is not really visible in the final document.
So i changed this:

```
<Viewpoint ... ></Viewpoint>
```

to this:

```
<Viewpoint ... > </Viewpoint>
```